# Implementation of BackHandler in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

Can someone explain me implementation of BackHandler and please also drop some examples with goBack function.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Import `BackHandler` like this ,  `import {BackHandler} from 'react-native';`

Step 2: Register a user define method with `BackHandler` and unregistered it while component detach so we have to write the code inside `componentDidMount()` and `componentWillUnmount()` so here is the steps.

```
componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
}

handleBackPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack(null)
    return true;
}
```